# Is it possible to create target for XCFramework inside workspace and use it as dependency?

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

We have XCode workspace which consists of 3 projects - two frameworks and application:

- One framework (KMPFramework) is written in Kotlin Multi Platform and is built by gradle - currently it is wrapped as Framework target with "Run Script" phase which calls gradle to build it
- Two frameworks (FrameworkA, FrameworkB) are normal frameworks - both of them uses KMPFramework as dependency
- One Application - which in fact is very simple and just calls methods from FrameworkA and FrameworkB

We distribute application via app store and also distribute frameworks to our customers so they can write they own application.

For now everything works fine, but we want to migrate our frameworks to XCFramework, to add support for ios simulator on Apple Silicon computers.

As first step, we modified gradle files so KMP generates XCFramewok for us, but looks like XCode does not provides target for XCFramework, so we can not use old approach with defining simple target with run-script phase and then use this target as dependency for FrameworkA and FrameworkB.

Currently i came into following solution:

- Removed target for KMPFramework from XCode
- Added Build -> Pre-Actions -> Run script action for Application target, in this pre-action i'm calling script which builds KMPFramework as XCFramework
- Added produced XCFramework as dependency to FrameworkA and FrameworkB

Overall it works, but there are few issues which i don't know how to solve:

- pre-action does not provides active architecture, so gradle builds all 3 available architectures for KMPFramework, which takes too much time for our internal developers
- pre-action runs even before clean - we found out that checking value of CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER_MODE (it has Deep for Clean action and Shallow for build action) can be used as workaround, but this doesn't looks quite good
- pre-action overall doesn't looks very well in this case and seems to be quite hacky

I also tried to use different configuration of targets (Framework, Aggregate, External Build System), but XCode verifies existence of XCFramework on very beginning of build process and fails if it not yet exists.